# Правильно ли я понимаю array.map?

Tags: javascript, массивы, map

Сейчас выучил метод массива map, по началу было сложно, но вроде как разобрался и вот хочу спросить, правильно ли я все понял?

```js
let names = ["Ivan", "Andrew", "Gleb", "Sasha"];

let namesData = names.map(name => name.length)
    
console.log(namesData)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>map test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код выше я понимаю так:

В первой строке я создаю массив с именами, далее создаю второй массив который будет хранить в себе результаты вызова names.map

name - это элемент который будет хранить в себе весь код стрелочной функции.

Выходит что первый массив дает нам данные с которыми мы будем работать, результат "маппинга" в себе будет хранить второй массив, а код который пишется в стрелочной функции - это работа с данными из первого массива. Правильно?

Comment: "поначалу" пишется вместе

Comment: "хранить в себе весь код стрелочной функции" - ?? `name` - это параметр стрелочной функции

Comment: в итоге вопрос по map или по стрелочным функциям?)

Comment: "Выходит что первый массив дает нам данные с которыми мы будем работать" --- да ... "результат "маппинга" в себе будет хранить второй массив" --- да ......"код который пишется в стрелочной функции - это работа с данными из первого массива" ---  Функция, вызываемая для каждого элемента массива

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, могли бы вы написать такой же ответ чтобы я мог его пометить как лучший?

Comment: Вам будет проще понять что делает `map` если вы напишете его сами.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy этот map я написал сам

Comment: Я имел в виду написать самому реализацию метод `map`, не его использование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всё правильно поняли, кроме “name – это элемент который будет хранить в себе весь код стрелочной функции.” `name` не хранит код стрелочной функции, а является *частью* этой функции. При выполнении `map`, `name` будет иметь значения элементов массива. В вашем примере, вначале значение `name` будет равняться `"Ivan"`. Потом `"Andrew"`. Потом `"Gleb"`. И наконец `"Sasha"`.

Такой подход называется функциональным программированием, и очень часто встречается, когда нужно работать с массивами. Альтернатива — использование циклов. Обычно считается, что функциональный подход лучше, то есть код, использующий его легче читать и изменять.

Две другие функции в JavaScript, которые тесно связаны с map, это filter и reduce.

Comment: `console.log(["Ivan", "Andrew", "Gleb", "Sasha"].map(name => name.length))` - для меня вот как должно выглядеть функциональное программирование)) А `forEach` не связан тесно?)

Comment: @Leonid: forEach я не указал из за side effects, и их за его схожести с обычными циклами.

Comment: _«forEach я не указал из за side effects»_ - в самом методе нет никаких побочек, т.е. ничто не мешает использовать его чисто (кейс: просто вызов методов каждого из объектов во входном массиве, типа `const markAll(items) => (items.forEach(itm => itm.mark()), items);`). Ну и, ТС не все понял правильно... он сущность параметра `name` истолковал неверно - соотв., рекомендую поправить ответ, пока минусов не насовали :)

Comment: @yar85: Если нет побочных эффектов, то вызывать forEach нет никакого смысла. См. [к примеру](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) «Example side effects include modifying a non-local variable, modifying a static local variable, **modifying a mutable argument passed by reference**, performing I/O, [...]». В вашем примере, я понимаю mark изменяет что-то в itm, и следовательно создаёт побочный эффект. Что касается параметра name, да, я не заметил это вначале. Спасибо. Ответ исправил.

Comment: Изменения увидел, спасибо большое

Comment: @Arseni, в примере рассматривается прежде всего метод `forEach`, который: во-первых, не принимает аргументом объект - а вызывается **в контексте** "своего" объекта (`items`); во-вторых, он вызывает не метод `mark`, а локальный коллбэк который этот вызов выполняет (конечно, этот локальный коллбэк не является чистой функцией - это нормально... зачем ему быть таковой?); ну и в-третьих, очень странно что работа с внутренними данными объекта (эл-тами массива, в данном случае) тут названа побочным эффектом... разве сам смысл слова "побочный" не конфликтует со смыслом термина "контекстный объект"?

Comment: Может быть, за пример сойдет предположительно прототипный метод с вызовом вида `this.forEach(yesno => yesno.toggle());` - тут вызов метода `forEach` имхо чистый, т.к. не оперирует побочным состоянием (только локальным, своего объекта), и ничего не выводит; коллбэк - сам по себе нечистый, т.к. принимает параметром внешний объект (но объявлен локально, и поэтому сам вызов `forEach` от него не теряет чистоту); метод `toggle` чистый если не содержит вывода, т.к. оперирует только локальным состоянием своего объекта (также не нарушает чистоту, если не считать эл-ты `this` побочным состоянием).

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko в `map` можно передать `callback`, который исполняемый скрипт перепишет, не то, что побочные эффекты. Это же просто рамочные методы массива по соглашению, все зависит от функции, которую вы передаете в качестве параметра. Так или иначе под капотом все тот же цикл, но еще и создаваемая область памяти, ссылка на которую возвращается.

Comment: @yar85: В вашем примере, во время выполнения forEach, вы меняете первоначальный массив. А это является побочным эффектом. Попробуйте представить код, в котором *все* объекты одновременно const и *immutable* (например с deepFreeze). Можете найти пример использования map? Конечно. А вот forEach становится абсолютно бессмысленным.

Comment: @Arseni, нет, это **основной** эффект метода, а не побочный. Ну а иммутабельность данных может быть условием только идемпотентности, но не чистоты функций их использующих (и в данном случае, это не применяется: метод `mark`, если предположить его назначение в установке локального свойства в определенное конечное состояние - идемпотентен: потому что каким бы ни было состояние локального свойства в момент вызова, в результате выполнения оно изменится на определенное, соответствующее "отмечен").

Comment: Во втором случае - `toggle` не является идемпотентным методом, если предположить что он меняет локальное состояние на противоположное: результат зависит от начального состояния. Но оба "внешних" метода чистые, т.к. не работают с побочным (внешним/общим) состоянием: и не читают, и не изменяют его. Все что они делают, это меняют локальное состояние в соответствии со своим прямым назначением - и это уж никак нельзя назвать побочным эффектом: ни по верной терминологии, ни по здравому смыслу (но да, в неверной терминологии, или в извращенном смысле - возможно, они не чистые... с этим я не спорю).

Comment: Если вместо контекстного объекта мы представим локальное окружение родительской функции (все свойства, включая вложенные, в его состоянии разложим по локальным переменным; и методы развернем в "плоский" процедурный код), то получим полную чистоту такой функции. Это же настолько очевидно! Здесь просто отсутствует какое-либо участие побочного состояния (side/shared state) - так почему же говорится о наличии побочных эффектов, в чем именно они заключаются?

Comment: @yar85: Давайте, чтобы наше общение было конструктивным, опираться на определения терминов, и на логику. (1) [Определение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) английской Википедии термина «побочный эффект» вас устраивает? (2) Если да, то наверное нужно определить, является ли items из вашего примера «a mutable argument passed by reference». Думаю с by value/by reference у нас разногласий нет? Согласны, что items передается be reference? (3) Также, я думаю, вы согласны с тем, что item является mutable?

Comment: (4) А вот является ли он аргументом или нет, тут возможно вы скажете, что нет, так? Если так, то как вы его определяете? Если это не аргумент, то что это? Как это называется? Попробуйте, например, переписать forEach в форме функции – не метода, а именно функции. Как будет выглядеть такая функция?

Comment: @Arseni, (1) определение википедии не устраивает, его двусмысленностью; (3) да, конечно согласен; (4) является аргументом локальной коллбэк-функции, но не `forEach` - у последнего, нулевым аргументом является его контекстный объект (массив или массивоподобный объект, и первым аргументом тот самый коллбэк. Переписывать `forEach` функцией будет неадекватно ситуации: адекватным аналогом будет процедурный цикл.

Comment: @yar85: Думаю, я понимаю, в чем у нас несогласие. Вы считаете, что scope forEach в данном случае, это сам массив, и следовательно изменение массива не может считаться побочным эффектом, аналогично тому, как например (x, y) => ({ const sum = x + y; return sum / 2; }) не может считаться функцией с побочными эффектами только потому, что она использует переменную. Правильно?

Comment: Если да, то это не совсем верный подход, и возможно именно поэтому определение побочного эффекта вам кажется двусмысленным. Термин «функция», в данном случае, означает именно функцию, как её понимают в математике. Прототип (или метод в Java и других языках) не считается: его нужно сначала переписать в виде функции.

Comment: Вот [статья](https://blog.pelicandd.com/article/194), которую я сейчас написал как продолжение нашего общения. В ней два доказательства того, что тот пример, который вы привели с yes/no массивом содержит побочные эффекты. Предлагаю обратить особое внимание на второе доказательство, которое я нахожу достаточно элегантным (и которое проще понять, чем первое). Если есть вопросы, обращайтесь. Мой электронный адрес указан в моем профиле на ru.stackoverflow.

Comment: @Arseni, в том и проблема, что приверженцы FP пытаются натягивать математический смысл функции на абсолютно любой практический контекст - и поэтому, ошибаются: ведь строго говоря, чистые функции возможны только в машинном языке, но в нем нет самой сущности "функция" (в большинстве аппаратных архитектур) - и это приводит к парадоксу который принято прятать за оголтелой долбежкой "каноничным" определением, ложным в самой основе :( Это неразумно. Для того чтобы прийти к адекватному определению - требуется принять факт допущений в каноничном определении, и расширить их на практический контекст.

Comment: @Arseni, другими словами: для восприятия адекватного практическому применению принципов, требуется слегка "придушить" в себе оперирующего безупречными абстракциями математика, и обратить внимание на потребность в ряде поправок (допущений) - которая естественным образом возникает в прикладной сфере (в программировании), т.е. при попытках применения совершенной математики к несовершенному реальному миру. Так мы приходим к осознанию того что чистота возможна лишь условно, и здравая мера этой условности определяется **реальной технической возможностью** (не терминологией). Все имхо, не ради спора.

Comment: Короче, я совсем не заявляю что возможности JS позволяют заниматься "правильным" функциональным программированием - это было бы просто нелепо, учитывая высокоуровневость языка и его реализацию функций объектами. Только выражаю такое мнение, что при той мере чистоты которая вообще возможна в этом языке, сам метод `forEach` не уступает своим "родственникам": если считать что чистым может быть использование например `map`, то таковым может быть и использование `forEach` (именно "может быть", а не "является"!.. и пожалуйста, не стоит сводить все к примерам, игнорируя общую смысловую суть тезиса).

Comment: @yar85: Понятно. Давайте тогда рассуждать практически. Для чего, *на практике*, нужно знать, есть ли у функции побочный эффект, или нет? Например, функции без побочных эффектов можно вызывать несколько раз вместо одного (хоть и без гарантии того, что return value будет одно и то же). Это важно, например, при использовании итераторов в JavaScript. Что получится если функцию из вашего примера выполнить дважды, вместо одного раза?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128832/discussion-between-yar85-and-arseni-mourzenko).